# Send messages to a global buffer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, buffer, stdout

I know global variables aren't encouraged in Ruby but this is what I have been asked to do so you'll just have to go with me on this. I have a game that outputs messages to the command window successfully through the STDOUT. My task is to modify the class so that the messages are not only displayed to the STDOUT channel but also written to a buffer. This is so when I add an additional Sinatra method to the end of the file, the buffer is displayed in a browser (i.e localhost:4567).

So effectively, with the Sinatra gem called, running the `spec.rb` from a command window should result in the messages being displayed in the Web server in addition to the command window. But I do not know where to start in terms of outputting my messages to the buffer.

I'm pretty sure there is a very simple answer to this but my knowledge of ruby is not great. My thinking is I need to add a line to each activity concatenating the output of each to the global variable $buffer but how do I do this? Obviously following that, I need to write a Sinatra method that displays the contents of the global variable in the web browser.

Hope that makes sense.

I have two files, spec.rb and gen.rb. This is my code so far:

**spec.rb**

```
require "gen.rb"

module ImpossibleMachine
    # Input and output constants processed by subprocesses
    DOWN_ARROW = 1
    UP_ARROW = 2
    RIGHT_ARROW = 3
    REPEAT_ARROW = 4
    END_PROCESS = 5 
    START_CURRENT = 6

    # RSpec Tests 
    describe Game do
        describe "#start The impossible machine game" do
            before(:each) do
                @process = []
                @output = double('output').as_null_object
                @game = Game.new(@output)
            end
            it "sends a welcome message" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with('Welcome to the Impossible Machine!')
                @game.start
            end
            it "sends a starting message" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with('Starting game...')
                @game.start         
            end
            it "should perform lifts_lever_turns_wheel activity which returns REPEAT_ARROW" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with("Input: #{UP_ARROW}, Activity: Heave_ho_squeek_squeek")
                @process[1] = @game.lifts_lever_turns_wheel(UP_ARROW)
                @process[1].should == REPEAT_ARROW
            end
            it "should perform turns_tap_on_pulls_down_seesaw activity which returns DOWN_ARROW" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with("Input: #{REPEAT_ARROW}, Activity: Drip_drip_creek_creek")
                @process[2] = @game.turns_tap_on_pulls_down_seesaw(REPEAT_ARROW)
                @process[2].should == DOWN_ARROW
            end
            it "should perform pulls_down_seezaw_starts_current activity which returns START_CURRENT" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with("Input: #{DOWN_ARROW}, Activity: Creek_creek_buzz_buzz")
                @process[2] = @game.pulls_down_seezaw_starts_current(DOWN_ARROW)
                @process[2].should == START_CURRENT
            end
            it "should perform starts_current_pushes_grove activity which returns RIGHT_ARROW" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with("Input: #{START_CURRENT}, Activity: Buzz_buzz_pow_wallop")
                @process[3] = @game.starts_current_pushes_grove(START_CURRENT)
                @process[3].should == RIGHT_ARROW
            end
            it "sends a finishing message" do
                @output.should_receive(:puts).with('...Game finished.')
                @game.finish            
            end
        end
    end
end
```

**gen.rb**

```
require 'sinatra'
$buffer = ""

# Main class module
module ImpossibleMachine
    # Input and output constants processed by subprocesses. MUST NOT change.
    DOWN_ARROW = 1
    UP_ARROW = 2
    RIGHT_ARROW = 3
    REPEAT_ARROW = 4
    END_PROCESS = 5 
    START_CURRENT = 6

    class Game
        attr_reader :process, :output
        attr_writer :process, :output

        def initialize(output)
            @output = output
            puts "[#{@output}]"
        end

        # All the code/methods aimed at passing the RSpect tests are below.

        def start
            @output.puts'Welcome to the Impossible Machine!'
            @output.puts'Starting game...'
        end

        def lifts_lever_turns_wheel(input)
            @input = input
            @output.puts 'Input: 2, Activity: Heave_ho_squeek_squeek'
            return REPEAT_ARROW
        end

        def turns_tap_on_pulls_down_seesaw(input)
            @input = input
            @output.puts 'Input: 4, Activity: Drip_drip_creek_creek'
            return DOWN_ARROW
        end

        def pulls_down_seezaw_starts_current(input)
            @input = input
            @output.puts 'Input: 1, Activity: Creek_creek_buzz_buzz'
            return START_CURRENT
        end

        def starts_current_pushes_grove(input)
            @input = input
            @output.puts 'Input: 6, Activity: Buzz_buzz_pow_wallop'
            return RIGHT_ARROW
        end

        def finish
            @output.puts'...Game finished.'
        end
    end
end

# Main program

module ImpossibleMachine
    @process = []
    g = Game.new(STDOUT)

    # All code added to output the activity messages to the command line window is below.

    g.start
            @process[0] = g.lifts_lever_turns_wheel(2)
            @process[1] = g.turns_tap_on_pulls_down_seesaw(@process[0])
            @process[2] = g.pulls_down_seezaw_starts_current(@process[1])
            @process[3] = g.starts_current_pushes_grove(@process[2])
    g.finish
end

# Any sinatra code added to output the activity messages to a browser should be added below.



# End program
```

Comment: Look into IO and StringIO: `g = Game.new(my_special_io)`.

Comment: You know that `rspec` is for testing, and Sinatra is a web-server, they don't live together (unless you are _testing sinatra_, in which case, there is no browser...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

managed to get this to work after hours!
At the top add/adjust to:

```
require 'stringio'
$buffer= StringIO.new
```

in the main program:

```
g = Game.new($buffer)
g.start
@process[0] = g.lifts_lever_turns_wheel(2)
etc......
g.finish
puts $buffer.string #this sends it to stdout
```

then just add in the sinatra coding at the bottom which will also use $buffer.string

possibly not the best or smartest way to do it but it uses the global buffer they wanted and gets it to sinatra and the cmd line.

Comment: Thanks Claire! You're a hero

Comment: Out of interest, is your program an interactive game or does it just print output to the browser? I'm just failing to see the point in this app.

Comment: I agree, mine just prints out the output. That was my only concern that perhaps it was required to be interactive. I think because the purpose is for TDD, it is not required as such.

Comment: I have clarified this with Nigel Beachem and only output is required, no interactivity.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just create some sort of buffer object in your main program and pass it in the game, just like you pass in STDOUT.  Then you could call write methods on the passed in object inside the game.